# How to integrate Bluetooth headphones to control playback on Linux (Mint) players?

Tags: bluetooth, linux-mint, headphones

My headphones are WH-1000xm3. System being used is Linux Mint.
How to make playback work?

Answer (score 0):

1. install playerctl

```
    wget http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/playerctl/libplayerctl2_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/playerctl/playerctl_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libplayerctl2_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb playerctl_2.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```

2. install xbindkeys
3. Add command to a `~/.xbindkeysrc` file:

```
"playerctl play-pause"
    m:0x0 + c:208
    XF86AudioMute
```

This way you can control chrome, vlc, video/audio players playback remotely via your headphones

**This is tested for Linux Mind 19.3 Tricia with Sony WH-1000XM3**

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you came up with the content of the .`xbindkeysrc` file? I tried your config with the WH-1000XM4. Pausing works but resuming does not. Also, the headphones seem to use their own volume on top of the OS one. This is on arch + cinnamon (5.0.5).